# New theme creation and plugin Installation

Tags: wordpress, photo-gallery

### How to install Plugin in newly created theme

I am converting an html site to Wordpress. For my gallery i installed a "jQuery Lightbox For Native Galleries". But it is not working with my new theme. I don't know the issue. Somebody please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error it is giving ?

Answer (score 0):

There might be jQuery conflicting. For avoiding jQuery confliction make sure you are calling latest jQuery library ones in your theme.

Regards